# Modifying IP Whois results?

Tags: ip, dedicated-server, whois

Okay, I recently bought a dedicated server from santrex.net

If you go here: http://domaintoip.com/ip.php?domain=188.72.215.27

It displays the whois information for that IP, santrex.net

I want to modify my whois information, so that it displays my information instead, and doesn't link to santrex or santrex's ISP at all.

Is this possible? If so, how would I go about doing it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WHOIS information is stored by registrars for blocks, not individual IP addresses. In your case, RIPE provides WHOIS information for the block 188.72.215.0/23, consisting of 512 addresses, which was *allocated* to Santrex. Santrex can expand their entry, detailing which IP addresses they have *assigned* to their customers, but it will show up below the general information for the whole block. Some ISP do this, I have a block of 64 IPs assigned to my employer listed in WHOIS. So you should contact Santrex about it.

Comment: Could Santrex modify the information for a single IP address if I asked them?

Comment: @Rob Could they, sure. Would they? probably not  - it's a lot of work to manage each IP. (The last company I worked for could do this, but only if your customer assignment was a single IP -- e.g. shared hosting.)  Also note that the initial delegation from the RIR will almost definitely still show up in the whois output (unless you're getting your block directly from the RIR)

Comment: @Rob I agree with voretaq7, it's pretty unlikely they will modify it for you...

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Prof. Moriarti's answer, note that your ISP may also use RWHOIS instead of sending updates to the WHOIS servers (SWIP).
If the whois output includes a line like

```
ReferralServer: rwhois://rwhois.yourhost.com:4321
```

they're using RWHOIS.  (THe benefit from the ISP end is that they don't have the hassle of sending updates to the WHOIS gods every time they assign/reclaim space).

If they're using RWHOIS your info won't show up in the WHOIS query unless the WHOIS client being used processes the `ReferralServer:` data and follows the referral...